# Destructor method for a linked list?

Tags: c++

Say I want to implement a destructor for a linked list function:

```
class LinkedList {
        public:
            LinkedList(int value, LinkedList* next);
            ~LinkedList();
            int value();
            LinkedList* next();
        private:
            int value;
            LinkedList* next;
}
```

My first thought was something like this:

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList {
    LinkedList* first = this;
    while (first != null) {
        LinkedList* temp = first->next;
        delete first;
        first = temp;
    }
}
```

This obviously does not work, since we have a `delete this` call which recursively calls itself forever. But I'm not sure how to get around this. My next thought was this:

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList() {
    delete next;
}
```

But I'm not sure if this actually does anything, since it just keeps recursively calls the delete method of `next` until ultimately ending on `NULL`. How would I go about implementing a destructor method for this implementation of a LinkedList?

Comment: "there is no pointer to the head," - erm , what?

Comment: You seem to have attempted to build the linked list into the list's links. Don't do this. Have two classes. One linked list with the head pointer and functions to insert to, delete from, and otherwise modify the list. And one link class which contains the data, a pointer to the next link, and pretty much nothing else.

Comment: @user4581301 I understand your point, and for practical pursposes, I will do that. But for the sake of learning, for this implementation, how would I write a destructor?

Comment: Your destructor will not call itself if `next` is not pointing to `this`.

Comment: @FallaCoulibaly it technically does, just with a different base-pointer and of course stopping the recursion once it hits a nullptr

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks @PeterT I will go to bed  wiser man.

Comment: How does your last example call itself recursively? Granted you will call the constructor, but hopefully it will call the destructor for another object, namely the next element in the list. When you reach the end of the list the `next` pointer should be `NULL` and then the recursion should end (IIRC the language does the check automatically, `delete`ing `NULL` is a no-op).

Comment: My thought process for the last one is as follows: all the destructor method does is call the destructor method of next. All the destructor of next does is call the destructor of next->next. Ultimately, this will all end when calling delete on NULL. So I don't see how any progress is made.

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    delete next;
}
```

Should work. If you have a list like: `A -> B -> C -> D` and delete `A` (which is your head), the destructor for `A` will delete and call the destructor for `B`, which will delete and call the destructor for `C`, and so on. `D`'s destructor have `next = nullptr`, so the delete does nothing.

However, if you have a very long list and the destructor is not tail call optimised by the compiler, you might encounter a stack overflow.

Comment: Where this concept falls down is you have to be extra careful when you remove a node from the list. If next is not NULLed on removal, it will obliterate everything after it in the list when destroyed.